# How much column mapping in phalcon models impacts performance?

Tags: php, model, phalcon

Does column mapping Phalcon\Mvc\Model column mapping impact performance?
I am working on application, that would be under highloads and i am worrying about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column renaming adds a minimal overhead but not considerable in terms of performance. Usually, bottlenecks are connecting/accessing/reading/writing the database not the data manipulation.